# Last element in nav not in center

Tags: css

I have centered all text within the `li` tags but, for some reason, the last one is slightly closer to the bottom. Here is the code and the picture:

[image: Picture of result]

```css
    *{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing:border-box}
    
    #hamburgerClick{
        display:block;
           width:65px;
      height:65px;
      position: fixed;
      overflow: hidden;
      top:50px;
      left:50px;
      cursor: pointer;
      z-index:9999999999999;
    }
    header h1{
        width: 100%;
        text-align:center;
        color:white;
        background: #252525;
    }
    header{
        flex-direction: column;
        padding:0;
    }
    header ul{
        flex-direction: column;
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
        height:100vh;

         display:flex;
    list-style:none;
    transition: ease .8s;
    justify-content: space-between;
    }

    .ultog{
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
    header ul li{
          text-align:center;
    width:6em;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width:100%;
        height: 100vh;
        background:#131313;
        color:white;
        border-top: 2px solid #252525;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        font-size:2em;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin:0;

    }
    header ul li:nth-child(1){
        border: none;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="hamburgerClick">
        <div id="hamburger"></div>
        <div id="hamburger2"></div>
        <div id="hamburger3"></div>

    </div>
    <header id="header">
        <h1>Photo21</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Products</li>
            <li>Career</li>
            <li>About us</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
    </header>
```

Comment: it seems like the problem is that you gave `100vh` to `li`, but in your page you have something that outside of that (photo21). It would be easier to help if you could post the html as well

Comment: It would be kinda tricky to post the whole HTML but here's what's going on:
I have my header set like this     <header id="header">
       ` <h1>Photo21</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Products</li>
            <li>Career</li>
            <li>About us</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
    </header>`

And when the side nav is opened, it's set to flex and flex-direction changes to column. It's seems that you're right, the h1 at the top is pushing the list downwards and now I'm trying to figure out how to make the list take the remaining space

Comment: @user4642212 I just did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments, the problem is that your ul has a height of 100vh (all the window), but then you have an `h1` on top of that. So your total height is the height of the `h1` plus `100vh`.

A possible solution is to set the h1 to a fixed height (I used 40px as an example), and then add this for your ul:

```
height:calc(100vh - 40px);
```

You can see a snippet here  below (open it in full page to see the correct behavior):

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing:border-box}
    
    #hamburgerClick{
        display:block;
           width:65px;
      height:65px;
      position: fixed;
      overflow: hidden;
      top:50px;
      left:50px;
      cursor: pointer;
      z-index:9999999999999;
    }
    header h1{
        width: 100%;
        text-align:center;
        height: 40px;
        color:white;
        background: #252525;
    }
    header{
        flex-direction: column;
        padding:0;
    }
    header ul{
        flex-direction: column;
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
        height:calc(100vh - 40px);

         display:flex;
    list-style:none;
    transition: ease .8s;
    justify-content: space-between;
    }

    .ultog{
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
    header ul li{
          text-align:center;
    width:6em;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width:100%;
        height: 100vh;
        background:#131313;
        color:white;
        border-top: 2px solid #252525;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        font-size:2em;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin:0;

    }
    header ul li:nth-child(1){
        border: none;
    }
```

```html
<div id="hamburgerClick">
        <div id="hamburger"></div>
        <div id="hamburger2"></div>
        <div id="hamburger3"></div>

    </div>
    <header id="header">
        <h1>Photo21</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Products</li>
            <li>Career</li>
            <li>About us</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
    </header>
```